# View network computers in c# application

Tags: c#, networking

I have a number of computers on my local network at home.  Two of them are running Win7 and one running Win8.  There are a couple of others but they are irrelevant at the moment.  In Windows when i click on the network tab, i am able to view all the pc's one the local network.

I am looking to write a console application that can perform tasks on shared folders that are available on the network.  When i run "net view" on all of the computers, it is only returning the local pc that the command is run on.  I tried "net view" due to the fact that when i googled for a c# solution the most common response i have found is....

```
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:");
foreach (DirectoryEntry computers in root.Children)
{
    foreach (DirectoryEntry computer in computers.Children)
    {
        if (computer.Name != "Schema")
        {
         textBox1.Text += computer.Name + "\r\n";
        }
    }
}
```

There are a few variations on this code, but they tend to be very similar.  This code that i posted is only returning the local pc that the code is written on.

I can't understand why i can see all the computers in windows, yet the "net view" command and this code only returns the local pc.

Any help would be good

Thanks